# How can I determine the total energy and power provided by an ocean wave when it reaches shore?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, fluid-statics, tidal-effect, oceanography

When an ocean wave travels to the shoreline and breaks, how much energy is released? I did some research on finding out a formula to calculate how much energy is stored and then released by ocean waves, but I've found some conflicting information. One source told me it's a direct correlation with the kinetic energy formula, and by replacing some variables, we would get Equation 2 (see image 1). However, I'm not sure if this formula is correct or how we would even get to this formula from the kinetic energy equation. I would think Equation 2 (image 2) is closer to the kinetic energy equation, but I'm not sure if this is correct approach either.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Equation 1]

- (T - Wave period (time between successive peaks (s)))
- (H - Wave height (distance from trough to peak (m)))

[image: Equation 2]

Comment: Please avoid screenshots as much as possible. Especially equations, that can be typeset with Mathjax provided on this site.